# how to fix docker crashing at startup

Tags: docker, startup, docker-desktop

I am giving the error image below-
[image]
My build number-
[image]
My pc details-
[image]
*I am new to docker and i first installed docker and ran into some tutorial and at first day it was working fine but from next day i ran into this error and i tried the below steps also*--

1. Uninstall and install again
2. Update wsl 2
3. reboot docker
4. reset docker hyper-v, wsl2 and all cache and container
5. Trobleshoot but it didnot helped
6. Factory reset

But still the problem persists . So what can i do to solve this problem? i had this problem from 1 week ago and cant use docker since then.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Which version and build of Windows OS you are using? What is RAM/CPU config?
Did upgrade to WSL2 worked fine?

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya i uploaded the build number and all pc details in 2 pic above ,,kindly check

Comment: Not sure if you got latest wsl2 , some issue logged in guthub for the same -https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5880

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya i even downloaded wsl 2 update package from docker official site and when i type wsl or wsl 2 in command propmt , i get this "The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it."

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I just installed Docker Desktop on Windows 10.  I (seemingly) fixed it by snoozing my VPN (Private Internet Access).  I'm not sure yet if the problem is fully resolved, but I'm getting further in the program than I ever have before.